# Why does my nasm x86 assembly code cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, fault

I don't know why my x86 assembly program causes a segmentation fault

code:

```
section .data
    msg:        db          'Number: %i', 10, 0

section .text
    global  main
    extern  printf
    extern  exit

main:
    mov     eax, 0

    mov     al, 10
    mov     dl, 10
    mul     dl

    push    eax
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4

    push    0
    call    exit
```

What can I do to avoid that problem and what causes it?

Comment: You forgot to `push msg`.

Comment: ohh... I'm embarrassed xD thanks :D

Comment: Which will also mean that you need to `add esp, 8`, but I assume you knew that already. In other news, it is more efficient to clear a register by doing `xor eax, eax` than `mov eax, 0`. Similarly, it would be better to do `mov al, 10`+`mov dl, al`, since reg-reg moves are shorter to encode than reg-imm moves.

Comment: @CodyGray: Actually `mov r8, imm8` is still only 2 bytes.  Just like `mov r32, imm32`, there's a separate opcode for each dest reg, with a separate `mov r/m8, imm8` opcode for memory destinations.  8086 spent opcodes pretty gratuitously, but this was probably justified at the time.  I think it got a lot of use in code using BIOS interrupts.

Comment: Why do you even use `DL` ? You can use `mov al,10` `mul al` to calc 10x10.